# How can I update the twilio chat channel attributes property with Twilio CLI

Tags: twilio, chat, twilio-cli

i'm trying to update a chat channel with the new Twilio CLI. I want to modify the attributes property but i'm no able to do that.

This is what I did.
[image]

and I got the next message
`» Error code 50304 from Twilio: Attributes not valid JSON. See https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/50304 for more info.`

I don't know how to send the `--attributes` json property.

Can somebody help me pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to I was using powershell.

If you have this problem in Windows you can use CMD and it works like a charm!

Greetings.